# Sampling with parameters in SAS

Tags: random, parameters, sas, set, sample

I have a large dataset dataset with 20 columns, and the columns "ltv", that contains the classification high, low and medium and "ticket" that contains values. I need 500 samples from dataset with "ltv" 70% low, 20% medium, 10% low and "ticket" between 252.00 and 300.00. How can I get this in SAS?

Answer (score 0):

You would use PROC SURVEYSELECT with stratification on the ltv variable.
You can specify the differing sampling rate with the samprate option.

Example:

```
proc surveyselect data = have out = want method = srs 
                  samprate = (.7 .2 .1) seed = 9876;
where ticket between 252 and 300;
strata ltv;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @Reeza. If I need to add one more variable in the result? I also have the column "gender" and I need put in the sample 70% M gender and 30% F gender. How can I get this using this new variable, adding to previus code?

Comment: That gets more complicated, see Example 3 here: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-take-a-stratified-random-sample-of-my-data/